# Unknown column in field list nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code in nodejs. I am using npm's mysql library and I know that all the columns are correct in mysql database but I keep getting the following error: "Unknown column 's3_id' in 'field list'" but when I do select s3_id from custom_videos I get rows back. How can I have an unknown column that exists?

```
router.post("/submitCustomVideo", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = {};
    const {
      s3Id,
      name,
      renderTime,
      duration,
      description,
      selectedCategories,
      selectedKeywords,
      customFields
    } = req.body;
    const VALUES = {
      s3_id: s3Id,
      name,
      duration,
      description,
      render_time: renderTime,
      custom_fields: customFields
    };
    const updateCustomVideoInfoResult = await database.query(
      "call updateCustomVideoInfo(?)",
      [VALUES]
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

heres my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mystuff`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateCustomVideoInfo`(s3_id_param varchar(255), name_param varchar(255), duration_param int, description_param varchar(255), render_time_param int, custom_fields_param json)
BEGIN
UPDATE custom_videos SET name = name_param, duration = duration_param, description = description_param, render_time = render_time_param, custom_fields = custom_fields_param WHERE s3_id = s3_id_param;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the columns as a string and also check your datatype for columns.